# AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework causing InvalidOperationException after Persist.InsertOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am using `AutoMapper` and trying out `AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework`, specifically the `Persist<T>` method.

My "source" is a fairly large object graph that has been converted (by `AutoMapper`) into some `EntityFramework` entities. The parent entity is called `Log`.

In my experimental test, I do the following:

```
var mapper = collectionConfig.CreateMapper();
var persistence = dbContext.Logs.Persist(mapper);
var testLog = logs.First();  // "logs" is the output of an AutoMapper.Map of a collection.
persistence.InsertOrUpdate<Log>(testLog);

Assert.IsTrue(dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());
```

What happens is an exception at the `ChangeTracker.HasChanges` call:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' is part of the
>   object's key information and cannot be modified.

The stack trace is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32
>   ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolean detectOnly)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean
>   detectOnlyComplexProperties)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1
>   entries)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean
>   force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.HasChanges()

This is a fairly well-known and well-documented exception:  it happens when you have an existing `EntityFramework` entity object and attempt to change the value of one of its primary key property fields.

But I'm not doing that anywhere.

I never set an `Id` value anywhere in my code. (The value for the `Id` property comes from elsewhere and is set by `AutoMapper` when the list of `Log` objects is created. Because of the nature of the data I'm reasonably sure that an entry for the `testLog` object does already exist in the database.)

I've been able to save whole collections of `Log` entries, created by `AutoMapper`, to the database, through `EF`, so I don't think my `Log` entities or the object graph have the problem.  I think it's something `AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework` is somehow doing.

I did try the `Persist` method with a different, simpler entity, with many fewer child entities, and didn't have this problem. But I can't even tell from this error which object in the graph has the supposedly-changed `Id` value:  half the objects in this object graph have a primary key called `Id`.

I can confirm that the actual *value* of `testLog.Id` isn't changed by the `InsertOrUpdate`.  But my attempts to examine an `Entry<Log>` for `testLog` or even to look at `dbContext.Logs.Local` all cause the same exception to be thrown.

So:  anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Tyler Carlson` of [`AutoMapper.Collection`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection), I have an answer.

```
persistence.InsertOrUpdate<Log>(testLog);
```

The problem stemmed from `testLog` already being of type `Log`, which is the same type I'm using in `EntityFramework`.  As Tyler said:

> Automapper doesn't support mapping to itself, as it causes so many
>   problems.
>   [...]
>   What you should be doing is passing
>   the dto into the persist call, not the entity it mapped to. That
>   mapping will happen in the InsertOrUpdate call.

We also discovered that if your `Entity` and `Dto` objects share a common base class, and that base class contains the definition of the key fields, this will also happen.

So in my situation, where my `Entity` and `Dto` contained 95% of the same fields, derived from a common base class, I had to take the `Id` property that was the primary key out of the base class, and define it separately in the two classes.  That ensured that, while the properties had the same names, they weren't in any sense the same property from a `Reflection` point of view.

If you're curious about the details, the discussion is here:  [AutoMapper.Collection Issue 40](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/issues/40).